# How SQL Server agent calculates next run date for a job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

I am developing a system for scheduling task & I am following Microsoft SQL agent approach to schedule task.
I have replicated sysschedules table for capturing users scheduling occurrences and timings. 
Now I need to know how SQL Server get the Next_run_date and time from this table.

I have found solution on internet which are using sysjobhistory table to get the next run date, but in my case I have only sysschedules table. So, what is the formula to calculate the next_run_date and time for any job.

**Note**: I am not looking for entire code, concept/algorithm will work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the dbo.sysschedules table you will see all of the data needed to calculate the schedules.

The columns named `active_*` delimit the periods in which the jobs can run.

The columns named `freq_*` define the frequency of the job runs.  You will notice a `freq_type`, which defines a type of frequency, which drives how the `freq_interval` and other columns are interpreted.

Please read the definitions at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178644.aspx

EDIT: You can calculate the next_run_datetime by using one of the following:

```
sp_help_jobschedule @job_name = 'Jobname'
sp_help_jobschedule @job_id= '<job id guid>'
```

Since there can be several schedules you can also use the schedule_id as such:

```
sp_help_jobschedule @schedule_id = 1, @job_name = 'Jobname'
```

This will return a data set in which the last columns give the data, such as:

```
next_run_date   next_run_time   schedule_uid                             job_count
20141110        190000          301DC5D5-9569-49FA-8BC5-9129109AFA6A     1
```

And you can script out the msdb procedure `sp_help_jobschedule` to see the code in the procedure, in case you want to include some of that in your own script.